# How to define type hint to tell function to expect a type in python

Tags: python, type-hinting

For purposes of documenting my project/keeping code tidy i want to have a type hint for all my functions (i'm still rather new to the whole typing concept).

I want to tell a function to expect a data type, like str, bool, int, dict, etc. aka what you get by calling `type(a_var)`

I realize property setters exist, but writing one is not feasible for my usecase

```
class TypeValidator:
    def __init__(self,
                 type: **the crux of the problem**
                 ):
        self.type = type

    def validate(self, value):
        return isinstance(value, self.value)
```

edit: having reread my own question, i guess what i'm trying to ask is how do describe this in typing:

```
>>> type(type)
<class 'type'>
>>>
```

edit2: [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) is what i'm looking for, thanks to [Patrick Haugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6779307/patrick-haugh)

Comment: In python 3.6+ you can use the following `def foo(xs: List[str]) -> List[Human]:` where Human is a class. However, these types are ignored while interpreting, thus they just work for documentation

Comment: this assumes i know what the data type will be in advance, no? for my usecase, i do not...

Comment: [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) maybe? It's not super clear how you expect this to behave.

Comment: TypeVar was just what i was looking for, thank you